# Explain Ethercalc on web and how can we use it with node js

Tags: node.js, spreadsheet

I want to know more about ethercalc so can you please anyone explain me it? so can you please explain me that how can i install it and use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethercalc is a spreadsheet package in nodejs, By using this we can use web spreadsheet in our website. below is the command for how can i install it. After install node js then run below commands.

```
npm i -g ethercalc
ethercalc
```

To run this spreadsheet in localhost then put below url in browser.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```